# python selenium find element and click - is not clickable

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to click on the Download CSV button and can't find the right element to click on. Using the chrome driver with Selenium and getting the same error after trying several levels of elements shown in the screenshot from DropdownWrapper down to and including Download-Icon:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (318, 27).

here are some the statements I have tried and all result in the same error:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/button/svg/g/g/g/g').click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name('DropdownMenuWrapper-sc-1akf9v9-2').click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name('DownloadCsvButton-sc-1iuvgd5-2').click()
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="DropdownWrapper-sc-1akf9v9-1 kIEUeW" direction="right" content="[object Object]"><div class="DropdownMenuWrapper-sc-1akf9v9-2 iGSrFC"><div class="DropdownMenuContainer-sc-1akf9v9-0 dYvTtz" direction="right" content="[object Object]"><svg class="CloseIconWrapper-sc-1tws3k5-6 gmjDxQ Svg-sc-190khmc-0 emBxVZ" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 14 14" id="closeCsvTrialDropDown" size="15" color="slate"><g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g class="close-icon" transform="translate(-962.000000, -419.000000)" stroke-width="0.5" fill-rule="nonzero"><g transform="translate(211.000000, 405.000000)"><g id="Close-Icon" transform="translate(752.000000, 15.000000)"><path d="M11.147541,0.147540984 L6.3442623,4.95081967 C6.14754098,5.14754098 5.83606557,5.14754098 5.6557377,4.95081967 L0.852459016,0.147540984 C0.655737705,-0.0491803279 0.344262295,-0.0491803279 0.163934426,0.147540984 L0.163934426,0.147540984 C-0.0327868852,0.344262295 -0.0327868852,0.655737705 0.163934426,0.836065574 L4.96721311,5.63934426 C5.16393443,5.83606557 5.16393443,6.14754098 4.96721311,6.32786885 L0.147540984,11.147541 C-0.0491803279,11.3442623 -0.0491803279,11.6557377 0.147540984,11.8360656 L0.147540984,11.8360656 C0.344262295,12.0327869 0.655737705,12.0327869 0.836065574,11.8360656 L5.63934426,7.03278689 C5.83606557,6.83606557 6.14754098,6.83606557 6.32786885,7.03278689 L11.147541,11.852459 C11.3442623,12.0491803 11.6557377,12.0491803 11.8360656,11.852459 L11.8360656,11.852459 C12.0327869,11.6557377 12.0327869,11.3442623 11.8360656,11.1639344 L7.04918033,6.3442623 C6.85245902,6.14754098 6.85245902,5.83606557 7.04918033,5.6557377 L11.852459,0.852459016 C12.0491803,0.655737705 12.0491803,0.344262295 11.852459,0.163934426 L11.852459,0.163934426 C11.6557377,-0.0327868852 11.3442623,-0.0327868852 11.147541,0.147540984 Z" id="Close-Button"></path></g></g></g></g></svg><div class="TitleLabelWrapperOrange-sc-1tws3k5-2 fjIicO">Feature unavailable on free trial</div><div class="SubTitleLabelWrapper-sc-1tws3k5-1 eFPKTl">Upgrade today to download CSV Files</div><div class="ListOfItemsWrapper-sc-1tws3k5-4 jOguBA"><ul class="ListOfItems-sc-1tws3k5-3 fkvYOb"><li>Find a profitable product to sell today</li><li>Access Jungle Scout’s full suite of Amazon selling tools</li><li>Rely on the most accurate sales data in the industry</li><li>Unlock best-in-class training tutorials and courses</li><li>Join 225,000+ of the world’s top FBA sellers</li></ul></div><div class="PopupButtonWrapper-sc-1tws3k5-0 kmrTpx"><button class="CsvTrialButton-sc-1tws3k5-5 gcGSc ButtonWrapper-sc-1vti96x-0 dxrAIm"><div class="ButtonContent-sc-1vti96x-1 mNloU">Upgrade Now</div></button><button class="CsvTrialButton-sc-1tws3k5-5 gcGSc ButtonWrapper-sc-1vti96x-0 eInnCg"><div class="ButtonContent-sc-1vti96x-1 bosOtE">Learn More</div></button></div></div></div><button class="DownloadCsvButton-sc-1iuvgd5-2 hhVvqT">Download CSV<svg class="StyledDownloadIcon-sc-1iuvgd5-3 jDCjZI IconWrapper-b39pdp-0 huocMM" color="#222222" viewBox="0 0 15 15"><g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g id="Download---Icon" fill="#222222"><g id="Download-CSV-Button"><g id="Download-Icon" fill-rule="nonzero"><path d="M14.0625,8.27027027 C13.575,8.27027027 13.2375,8.61486486 13.2375,9.16216216 L13.2375,13.0540541 L1.7625,13.0540541 L1.7625,9.16216216 C1.7625,8.63513514 1.44375,8.27027027 0.9375,8.27027027 C0.43125,8.27027027 0.1125,8.61486486 0.1125,9.16216216 L0.1125,13.9459459 C0.1125,14.472973 0.43125,14.8378378 0.9375,14.8378378 L14.0625,14.8378378 C14.55,14.8378378 14.8875,14.4932432 14.8875,13.9459459 L14.8875,9.16216216 C14.8875,8.63513514 14.55,8.27027027 14.0625,8.27027027 Z" id="Shape"></path><path d="M7.5,0.162162162 C7.0125,0.162162162 6.675,0.506756757 6.675,1.05405405 L6.675,7.54054054 L5.775,6.56756757 C5.45625,6.22297297 4.95,6.22297297 4.63125,6.56756757 C4.3125,6.91216216 4.3125,7.45945946 4.63125,7.80405405 L6.91875,10.277027 C7.0875,10.4594595 7.33125,10.5405405 7.5,10.5405405 C7.74375,10.5405405 7.9125,10.4594595 8.08125,10.277027 L10.36875,7.80405405 C10.6875,7.45945946 10.6875,6.91216216 10.36875,6.56756757 C10.05,6.22297297 9.54375,6.22297297 9.225,6.56756757 L8.325,7.62162162 L8.325,1.05405405 C8.325,0.608108108 7.9125,0.162162162 7.5,0.162162162 Z" id="Shape"></path></g></g></g></g></svg></button></div>
```

and can only provide screenshots of the page , as a login is required:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try clicking on the element using `JavaScript` click.
You can do it like:

```
download_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='DropdownWrapper-sc-1akf9v9-1 kIEUeW']//button[contains(text(),'Download CSV')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download_button)
```

Comment: this worked @Sameer . Thanks